# Estoy aprendiendo con python actualizar agregar y eliminar

Tags: python, lista

Buenas Noches estoy me dejaron de tarea crear una lista de libros en donde pueda agregar eliminar y actualizar el caso es que lo intento con un ciclo for 
solo puedo actualizar por que cuando intento agregar o eliminar lo unico que hace es repetirme la pregunta que estableci en el input o en el caso cuando

Este es el del main

```
import libros

#user = usuarios.usuario2

books = libros.ListaLibros 

for i in range(0, len(books)) :

    pregunta = input('¿Desea agregar,actualizar o eliminar un libro?')

    if (pregunta== "agregar") :
            book = input("Digite el titulo del libro que desea agregar: ")
            books.insert(0, book)

    elif (pregunta=="eliminar") :
            booksDelete =input("Digite el titulo del libro que desea eliminar: ")
            books.remove(booksDelete)

    elif (pregunta=="actualizar") :

                    print(books[i])

    else :
            print("error")
```

y este es el de el archivo libros

```
libro1 = "Cocori"
libro2 = "El principito"
libro3 = "Harry Potter"
libro4 = "El señor de los anillos"
libro5   = "Los juegos del hambre"

ListaLibros = [libro1,libro2,libro4,libro5]
```

[image: Captura uno de mi IDE]

[image: Captura dos de mi IDE]

Comment: pon el `pregunta = input('...')` dentro del `for`

Comment: Yo le recomendaria que copiara y pegara el codigo en lugar de una imagen, se hace mas facil de apoyarle

Comment: Ya copie el codigo

Comment: Ya intente poner el input dentro del for pero cuando escribo actualizar solo me imprime un elemento de la lista

Comment: reemplaza `print(books[i])` por `print(books)`, `print(books[i])` dice imprime solo el libro de numero i, Ej: i = 4 imprime "Los juegos del hambre"

Comment: ['libro', 'Cocori', 'El principito', 'El señor de los anillos', 'Los juegos del hambre']    ahora me lo imprime asi

Comment: y cuando elimino un libro se sale

Comment: (https://repl.it/F6sE/0)

Answer (score 0):

Yo haria algo asi:

main.py:

```
import libros
books = libros.ListaLibros 
pregunta = input('¿Desea agregar,actualizar o eliminar un libro? Escriba salir para terminar')

while pregunta =! 'salir':

    if pregunta == "agregar":
        book = input("Digite el titulo del libro que desea agregar: ")
        books.insert(0, book)

    elif pregunta=="eliminar":
        booksDelete = input("Digite el titulo del libro que desea eliminar: ")
        books.remove(booksDelete)

    elif pregunta == "actualizar":
        bookActualizarOld = input("Digite el titulo del libro que desea actualizar: ")
        bookActualizarNew = input("Digite el nuevo titulo: ")
        books[books.index(bookActualizarOld)]=bookActualizarNew

    else :
        print("error")
print "Terminado!"
```

El libros.py queda tal cual esta.

Obviamente de esta manera no se guardaran los cambios, ya que con cada ejecución del script todo vuelve a 0.

Saludos desde Argentina!

Answer (score 0):

Así funciona, creo que como lo quieres.

También te podría sugerir que en lugar de pedirle al usuario que escriba una palabra, utilices números. Por ejemplo: *ingrese 1 para agregar, 2 para eliminar, 3 para actualizar y 4 para salir*.
Así puedes evitar que el usuario ingrese mal las palabras.

```py
import libros
books = libros.ListaLibros 
variable = 1

while variable != 0:
    pregunta = input('¿Desea agregar,actualizar o eliminar un libro? Escriba salir para terminar\n')

    if pregunta == 'agregar':
        book = input('Digite el titulo del libro que desea agregar: \n')
        books.insert(0, book)

    elif pregunta=="eliminar":
        booksDelete = input('Digite el titulo del libro que desea eliminar: \n')
        books.remove(booksDelete)

    elif (pregunta=='actualizar') :
        print(books)

    elif (pregunta=='salir') :
        variable=0

    else :
        print('error al ingresar opción')

print('Fin del programa')
```